# In how many ways can 100 identical chairs be distributed to five different classrooms ...

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

**In how many ways can 100 identical chairs be distributed to five different classrooms if the 2 largest rooms together recieve exactly half of the chairs?**

ive worked out a couple of these problems. the identical chairs seem to throw me off on this one any help ?

Comment: The classrooms are important not the chairs solve it in the ordinary way

Comment: The big classrooms are A and B, and the smaller ones C, D, and E. (i) Count the number of ways to distribute $50$ chairs between A and B; (ii) Multiply by the number of ways to distribute the other $50$ between C, D, and E.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

If you have

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = r$$

with a known pair $x_i + x_j = k$

Then by the stars and bars method the solution is

$C(r-2+n-1-k,r-k)$

Then you have to multiply this with
how many ways the $2$ largest rooms 
can get half the chairs.